# Using ArcGIS JavaScript API & highcharts libraries

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, chart

I'm working with jsviewer and JSAPI V:2.8.I to try to display a query result in a chart.

what I want to do is :first, I want to  query on my table and  once I got the result liste I have a button that displays the results in a chart.I want to use highcharts librairies.

Is there a code sample or any indication that could help me do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to post the code to you but the way to do it would be to query the arcgis server/or any other mapping server or even a database server and get the request to JSON object, Parse it and use the keys in json to use as the chart data.

get the json from arcgis server http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/1/query?where=STATE_NAME%3D%27Florida%27&f=json, use the json keys such as jsonobj["STATE_NAME"] and use it as data:jsonobj["STATE_NAME"] in your series.

Comment: Link is broken.